# .net monitor gc collection in production website

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

For some error analysis i would like to monitor when the GC is performing a collection .

In this article i found that there are "WaitFor....()" methods but this seemsquite ugly for me as i have to spawn a thread which waits whole time for a gc just for logging purposes like this:

```
  while (checkForNotify)
  {
       // Check for a notification of an approaching collection.
       GCNotificationStatus s = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach(); 
       //.... log  start
       s = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
      /// log complete
}
```

Isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're monitoring a live site on a production server, I wouldn't be using the code base to monitor itself!

I would use PerfMon and monitor the GC statistics under the .Net hive.

MSDN has some reading material over here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perfmon might be a little outdated now, Resource Monitor might be better; but that article should still document the counters that you can read.

Comment: ResourceMonitor can show managed memory related stuff? Do you have a link? With performance mon i would have the performance counter

Comment: Oh, my bad, I meant to say System Monitor ... Apologies!